# UseKestre Limits.KeepAliveTimeout from appsettings

Tags: .net-core, appsettings, kestrel

Is this possible to read config file to get idle time before `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder...`?

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
   WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
          .UseStartup<Startup>()
          .UseKestrel(k => k.Limits.KeepAliveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(config.IdleTime));
```

When I try to read it, it always throw error that config is null.

UseKestrel keepAliveTimeout default value is 2, and it always take too much time to wakeup.

Any Idea how to read Idle value from config?

Answer (score 0):

I am using below method

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true)
            .AddCommandLine(args)
            .Build();

        // This config is passed to CreateWebHostBuilder
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args, config).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args, IConfigurationRoot config) =>
    //You can access config values now inside this method
```